# JavaScript multipart-form data is not retrievable to PHP codeigniter backend

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, axios

I'm trying to submit a form with files using javascript to a PHP Codeigniter backend. The javascript code looks like this,

```
            var card = {
                        user: {
                            my: {
                                firstname: this.user.my.firstname,
                                lastname: this.user.my.lastname 
                            }
                          }
                        }
            var form = new FormData()
            form.append('card', card)
            form.append('file', this.user.cover_file)

            axios({
                method: 'post',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
                data: form,
                url: 'url'
            })
```

And I am unable to retrieve the data from the PHP backend, the backend code looks like this,

```
public function newpost()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $user = $this->input->post('user');
    echo $user;
}
```

This does not show any output, what am I doing wrong here and why is the data not retrivable from the backend, thanks

Comment: I suppose callback should be defined.

Comment: No I mean the request should show some output in developer tools for the echo function. And that is blank. So it is making me believe that I'm handling the request incorrectly.

Comment: is it correct to call $this->input->post('user'); rather than $this->input->post('card'); ?